# Why is the radius of convergence $1$ here?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

My exercise it to prove that the radius convergence for $$\frac{1}{1+x}$$ is $1$. I figure I should use the ratio test to figure this out, and it is given to me that the series representing this function is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n $$

So, applying ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|  $$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{(-1)^nx^n}| < 1 $$

This is true if the series is convergent. After algebra:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |(-1)x|< 1 $$

$$x < 1$$.

Not sure if I can just drop the limit operator, but I don't know how to evaluate that as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I'm left with this, and I'm not exactly sure if this supports the case if the radius of convergence here is $1$. Here, $L$ is $x$, and for $L$ to be less than $1$, $x$ must be less than one. So.. maybe it's proving that the radius of convergence is one? I'm not confident with how I solved this exercise so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is almost correct, just one detail: $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}|(-1)x|=|x|$$ Why? You're evaluating a limit for $n$, and your function doesn't depend on n. So it's just a constant sequence. 
The absolute value is important. You know that the series converges if

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|<1$$

and you have

$$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=|x|$$

so you have convergence if $$ |x|<1$$

which is exactly what you want to prove.

Comment: I apologize if this sounds a bit ridiculous, but why does $|x| <1 $ explicitly tell me the radius of convergence is $1$? It just seems like to me $|x|$ must be between $-1 < x < 1$ to satisfy $|x| < 1$ which is a range of valid values exceeding $1$?

Comment: Check again the definition of radius of convergence: that limit tells you that the series converges, as you said, for $-1<x<1$, why do you think this exceeds one? Because of the negative values? Think of the radius of convergence like the literal "radius" of the interval, not the diameter. As a matter of fact in the complex plane this series converges in a literal disk of radius 1.

Comment: You've used the ratio test to find that your series converges whenever $|x|<1$.  So the radius of convergence is at least $1$. Another part of the ratio test (or just inspection of the series) tells you that it diverges whenever $|x|>1$.  So the radius of convergence cannot be bigger than $1$. (Alternatively, look at the series for $x=1$ and see that it diverges, so again the radius of convergence can't be bigger than $1$.)  Therefore, the radius of convergence must be exactly $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have doubts, you can check with the other method of finding the radius of convergence, which gives you the result immediately here, with nary a computation to be suffered through.

By Cauchy-Hadamard
$$
1/R=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup|(-1)|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup 1=1\implies 1=R
$$